# Spring Boot Securing User Data URL modification

Tags: spring-boot, web-deployment

I'm using spirng boot with security to create habit tracker. I got my database, user and goals. The problem is I can access other user goals and edit them by changing goal id in the URL.

What is the solution? Should I encode the url or do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are so called ACLs. For complex applications read here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#domain-acls

For easy id cheeking you can use method-level security, eg. @PreAuthorize. 
Here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#el-pre-post-annotations

examples: http://websystique.com/spring-security/spring-security-4-method-security-using-preauthorize-postauthorize-secured-el/